# How do Casimir operators help us classify representations of the Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have found the following statement in Wikipedia: "The eigenvalues of all Casimir elements can be used to classify the representations of the Lie algebra", and I am having trouble understanding what is meant.

I tried to think of the simple example of the quadratic casimir $C_2$ in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ (or rather, in its universal envelopping algebra), there I found it to be the sum of the squares of the generators -as expected, since we know that the total angular momentum squared $L_1^2+L_2^2+L_3^2$ commutes with any of the individual $L_i$. However, how do the eigenvalues of $C_2$ help us to classify the representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Put simply: the Casimir elements each act as a scalar on each representation. The collection of these scalars determines the representation uniquely

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more what you mean when you say that the Casimir element "acts" on the representation?

Comment: Casimir elements are elements of the centre of the universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ of our Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ has a natural action on every $\mathfrak{g}$-representation